# .Cshtml is not opening correctly

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I am not getting how to explain the issue that I am facing. This is really embarrassing. When I am opening a .cshtml file it is showing in digit format like below.

```
1100000 00000 00000 000 000000 0000 00

1100000 10000  00000 000 000000 0000 00

1100000 10000  00000 000 000000 0000 00

1100000 10000  00000 000 000000 0000 00
```

[image]

And when I am opening different .cshtml files that are opening correctly in razor format.
I am not getting what is the issue. I have done lots of work in that .cshtml. and I don't want to lose that. Please help me to solve this issue so I can have the same .cshtml file again.

Comment: it looks like binary file. Try to open it in notepad and say what to you see.

Comment: I have tried with notepad but it is showing blank.

Comment: That's wierd. Couse .cshtm is basically text files. So are you sure that your file ok? As i can see in binary view you file empty =)

Comment: Usually that occurs when studio crashes while compiling.. or the compilation stops in the midway by some unexpected interrupts. I have been in the same with one of my controllers.

Comment: see this https://www.samnoble.co.uk/2014/11/30/visual-studio-crashes-and-a-corrupted-cs-file/